# Formatar datas no sql

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

Tenho um programa no c# (Visual Studio) de cadastro que contém uma textbox para receber uma data. Sabendo que o SQL grava a data no formato americano, como posso fazer para que o usuário digite a data no formato brasileiro e essa data possa ser salva com sucesso no banco? Da maneira que estou fazendo, o usuário digita a data no formato brasileiro, mas ocorre um erro ao salvar, pois o SQL está tentando salvar MM/dd/yyyy. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor? Desde já agradeço.

Abaixo o código que estou utilizando:

```
//Variável que recebe o cast no textbox 
var validaDataVenda = DateTime.Parse(txtDataVenda.Text); 
var validaDataPagto = DateTime.Parse(txtDataPagamento.Text); 

//Comando que insere os dados no banco, recebendo os textboxes como parâmetros
VendaDAO.InsertVenda(novoCodigo.ToString(), txtValor.Text, dataDaVenda.ToString(), dataDoPagamento.ToString(), txtCodigoCliente.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtCodigoProduto.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtQuantidadeRequerida.Text, recebido);
```

Se eu inserir "31/102016", por exemplo, ocorre este erro: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

Comment: De que forma está a ser feita a ligação entre a aplicação e o SQL? Entity Framework? ADO.NET?

Comment: Quando você passa a data para a rotina que insere no banco, você usa a string do textbox diretamente ou faz um cast para datetime?

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo ADO.NET.

Comment: @Intruso eu faço direto do textbox.

Comment: Faça o cast para datetime e passe o datetime para o parametro que vai ser usado no insert/update. Armazenamento (db) é armazenamento, GUI e formatação não precisam ser representadas da mesma forma no db.

Comment: @Intruso continua dando erro :( O problema é que o sql só aceita se for MM/dd/yyyy. Mas o usuário irá digitar dd/mm/yyyy no textbox.

Comment: Cole o código que pega o valor da tela e o codigo que faz o insert aqui. Também coloque o erro que o SQL retorna, o valor que representa a data  de um Datetime é interno e não dependende da formatação. Se você conseguiu fazer o cast, deveria funcionar.

Comment: //Variável que recebe o cast no textbox
var validaDataVenda = DateTime.Parse(txtDataVenda.Text);
var validaDataPagto = DateTime.Parse(txtDataPagamento.Text);

//Insere no banco recebendo os textbox como params
VendaDAO.InsertVenda(novoCodigo.ToString(), txtValor.Text, dataDaVenda.ToString(), dataDoPagamento.ToString(), txtCodigoCliente.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtCodigoProduto.SelectedValue.ToString(), txtQuantidadeRequerida.Text, recebido);

Se eu inserir "31/102016", por exemplo, ocorre este erro:
"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string".

Comment: @Intruso Editei minha pergunta para melhorar a visualização do código.

Comment: porque você precisa fazer dataDaVenda.ToString() ? Você testa se o valor do campo está nulo antes de fazer o cast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar da forma como está passando os parâmetros não ser a mais indicada, você deveria mandar os dados em seus tipos de dados sem "tostring" e realizar a gravação conforme o método utilizado abaixo.

Mas se quer enviar no formato de texto, melhor dar uma olhada neste artigo, que explica como você formata uma data de forma correta.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy

Agora não sei como é sua aplicação, para Web não recomendo inserts no banco sem utilizar parametros como no método abaixo para evitar Sql Injection.

Segue um exemplo de uma função que insere datas que resolve seu problema

```
public Boolean Insere(Clientes cadastro)
{
    Conexao banco = new Conexao();
    SqlConnection con = banco.Conectar();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO CLIENTES (NOME, EMAIL, TELEFONE, DATANASC) 
            VALUES (@nome, @email, @telefone, @datanasc)", con);

        con.Open();
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", cadastro.Nome);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", cadastro.Email);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", cadastro.Telefone);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datanasc", cadastro.DataNasc);

        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso!!! Muito obrigado.